# Why did I get empty cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I put my UITableView in UIScrollView > View > StackView.

And I implemented table view in View Controller as usual with numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt. Here's my extension.

```
extension OrderViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("DEBUG: orderItems.count - \(orderItems.count)")
    return orderItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OrderCell.id, for: indexPath) as! OrderCell
    cell.configure(orderItems[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

}

But my simulator actually shows empty cells. I already checked the orderItems array only has 2 members.

I guess it is because either auto layout or stack view. In the stack view, I gave height constraints for every views except table view since it has to have dynamic cell number.

I don't know what I have to change.

[image: my simulator with two array items]

[image: hierarchy of table view (no anchor of height)]
[table view's attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mcpp.png)

Comment: I think you need to give height constraint to tableview, then after reloading tableview with data change height constraint of tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your tableview has full height with related your view. Just add on viewDidLoad

```
yourTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

But if you want dynamic height for your tableview then do that;

1. Give a height constraint for your tableview
2. Create an IBOutlet for this constraint

After you reload your tableview

```
heightConstraint.constant = yourRowHeight * arrayCount
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Sorry but I added it and I got filled cells and big empty white space below them lmao...

Comment: I answered for simple way to hide free cells
If you want dynamic height for your tableview so you can do that

- Give a height constraint to your table view and create an IBOutlet for this constraint
- Then after you reload your table view 

heightconstraint.contant = yourrowheight * arraycount
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()